# displaying the results while retriving the data from database to search box using php ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm going to retrieve the data from database using simple ajax. As my code i'm getting output but in that if i'm going to search with the perticular letter "a" it not showing perticular word from db instead its showing all the name which contains the letter "a"

```
            <style>
            #main {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 100px;
            color: Green;
            width: 365px;
            }
            #display_results {
            color:#222222; padding:5px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            }
            </style>
            <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search_results").slideUp();
            $("#button_find").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            search_ajax_way();
            });
            $("#search_query").keyup(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            search_ajax_way();
            });
            });
            function search_ajax_way(){
            $("#search_results").show();
            var search_this=$("#search_query").val();
            $.post("search.php", {searchit : search_this}, function(data){
            $("#display_results").html(data);
            })
            }
            </script>


            <div id="main">
            <form id="searchform" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="Enter Name" size="55">
            </form>
            <div id="display_results"></div>
            </div>
```

search.php

```
        <?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("unable to connect");
    mysql_select_db("newdb",$con) or die("unable to select database"); 
    $term = strip_tags(($_POST['searchit']));
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term); // Attack Prevention
    if($term=="")
    echo "Enter Something to search";
    else{
    $query = mysql_query("select name from userdetail where name like '%{$term}%'");
    $string = '';
    if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $string .= "<b><a href='#'>".$row['name']."</a></b> - ";
    //$string .= $row['email']."";
    $string .= "\n";
    }
    }else{
    $string = "No matches found!";
    }
    echo $string;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: well, you are using LIKE search, what do you expect?

Comment: ya suppose it enter a, it has to show the name starts with a, but its showing all the other name contains the letter "a'

Comment: so remove the first wildcard

Answer (score 1):

If you only want words that start with the term, you only need the wildcard AFTER the term.

```
$query = mysql_query("select name from userdetail where name like '$term%'");
```

Answer (score -1):

try `"select name from userdetail where name like '%$term%'"`

[Reference Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: It is really not relevant, and `{`, `}` is for interpolation

Comment: It is still the same - with or without the additional interpolation, the query will not change